# Extract Domain related words

Tags: nlp

I am doing a research regarding on automatic text summarizing. So in order to weighting sentences I need to get words related to a particular field or domain like shown below.

```
Topic word - Car
Related words - engine, driver, road, break, accelerator
```

Is there any direct method that I can use like `wordnet synsets`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One very obvious way is to use gensim's word2vec [most_similar()](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/keyedvectors.html#gensim.models.keyedvectors.WordEmbeddingsKeyedVectors.most_similar) function to get the most related words to the queried word.

You can check an online version of how it works out here: https://projector.tensorflow.org/

Again it depends on what kind of relations you seek. Other useful methods include:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn

wn.synsets('car')
wn.synsets('car')[0].hyponyms()
```